# Is there a way to plot more than 1000 points in a scatter plot using the Highcharts .NET Wrapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I've seen some posts that mention a 1000 point limit, which is what I am encountering. I'm using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts
Perhaps there is a different way than to use, Highcharts with Chart.Type = ChartType.Scatter and Series with a ScatterSeries?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KarlZ, Where have you find this information about the point limit? The official Highcharts .NET wrapper doesn't have something like this. https://dotnet.highcharts.com/ Maybe you have a different format of data and the `turboThreshold` must be changed? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.turboThreshold

Comment: @SebastianWędzel 
Headline: .Take(1000) works, .Take(1001) does not.

I started with the code on this page: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=Scatter&theme=default 
But had to change but had to change Chart.Type = ChartType.Scatter (Or I would just get lines.) I got that to work fine. 
Next, I started to feed in my own data (even left the axes and titles the same, just changed the data). I thought maybe I had a data problem, but a long story short, from my data source, using .Take(1000) works fine. .Take(1001) there are no points on the chart.

Comment: I guess I should add that I used NuGet to install Highsoft.Highcharts v8.1.1.1 as I work on a proof of concept. Is there a limit on points until I make an actual purchase?

Comment: @KarlZ try to set the `series.turboThreshold` to 0 (to disable this option). API: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_plot_options_scatter.html#a3674387e934212eb1327e07c29678d9f

Comment: @KarlZ I add it as an answer. Please accept it - could be useful for others in the future. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - disabling the `series.turboThreshold` allows rendering a higher amount of points.

API: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_plot_options_scatter.html#a3674387e934212eb1327e07c29678d9f